# how to purchase verdana font, how to purchase roboto font

Tags: fonts

Does anyone have any experience in buying verdana font or roboto font for enterprise use? We are trying to buy these fronts for an application development. Incase next android version changes the basic fonts set we dont want to run into ui issues.

Comment: Why is tagged with enterprise-library?

Answer (score 0):

**Roboto** is an [apache licensed font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roboto), so you should be free to use it in commercial applications without licensing fears.

**Verdana** is a proprietary font, created by english typographer [Mathew Carter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdana) for Microsoft in 1996. This font is available under license, and I imagine it would be expensive (ikea use it as there corporate font - so expensive might be an understatement).

A good apache licensed alternative might be the Deja Vu font family which is available under a [copyright free](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=License) public domain usage.